# Get flash shared object from my domain

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, cookies

I am trying to clear flash cookies for a SWF that is hosted on my domain. Is it possible to get this flash cookie (sharedObject) so that it can be cleared? visiting [this](https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html) page shows my domain in the list of sites, but I want to be able to clear these from another SWF file which is drawn if the cookies are to be reset. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you created the shared object from a SWF on your domain and you want to clear the shared object from a different SWF on the same domain? Or you want to clear *all* shared objects on a domain from a SWF?

Comment: Either of those options would work, but ideally I could just wipe them all from my domain.

Comment: You won't be able to wipe them all from a domain without knowing what they are called. In other words you can't query what shared objects exist on a domain in the same way the Settings Manager shows you. Will expand in an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`SharedObject/clear()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#clear()) with some limitations:

- The SWF that clears the shared objects must be on the same domain as the SWF(s) that created the shared objects.
- The shared objects must be created with a path that both SWFs have access to. The easiest thing is to use `"/"` as the path so that all SWFs on the domain can access the shared object. The default path limits access to only the SWF that created the shared object.
- You must know the exact names of all the shared objects. In other words you cannot query for all shared objects on a domain, you have to know the shared object names (and paths). (You can, of course, keep your own registry of shared objects in a single known shared object, though.)

For example:

**domain.com/my/path/writer1.swf**

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedData1", "/");
so.data.something = "Something";
```

**domain.com/my/other/writer2.swf**

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedData2", "/");
so.data.stuff = "Stuff";
```

**domain.com/other/thing/writer3.swf**

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedData3", "/");
so.data.thing = "Thing";
```

**domain.com/eraser.swf**

```
SharedObject.getLocal("savedData1", "/").clear();
SharedObject.getLocal("savedData2", "/").clear();
SharedObject.getLocal("savedData3", "/").clear();
```

*or*

```
var sharedObjectNames:Array = ["savedData1", "savedData2", "savedData3"];
for each(var sharedObjectName:String in sharedObjectNames){
    SharedObject.getLocal(sharedObjectName, "/").clear();
}
```

Note that when you use `"/"` as the path you must be careful not to have name collisions.